# accent-insenstitive text in CartoDB - PostGreSQL unaccent function missing?

Tags: carto

I am trying to do accent-insensitive text matching, but PostGreSQL's [unaccent function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/unaccent.html) doesn’t appear to be available

SELECT unaccent('Hôtel');

function unaccent(unknown) does not exist

Is this function supported somehow in CartoDB? If not, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were running your own version of PostgreSQL, you'd need to build the extension, then CREATE it. Typically you'd go to your source and do something like

`cd /usr/local/src/postgresql-9.3.4/contrib/unaccent
make
make install`

and then in a `psql` session, you'd run

`CREATE EXTENSION UNACCENT;`

before you could use it. It doesn't seem as if CartoDB gives you access or permissions to do such a thing.

Comment: Thanks Eric! Agree about CartoDB permissions. Bummer ...